# Visual Studio 2013 hangs/freezes when trying to click the designer view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2013

my Visual Studio 2013 update 1 hangs/freezes when trying to click the designer view, after clicking "Design" I can not click "split" neather "Source". What can I do ? I already tried to set the "HTML (Web Forms) Editor " as "Default"... thanks for support.

That's what it showed me : http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1z1r32g&s=8#.UxSL54V9LXI
In VS2010 the same worked fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: where is the correct place to post that question ?

Comment: you would be better asking Microsoft.

Comment: I get this occasionally. Restarting my pc usually resolves this. I haven't been able to fix it in a more elegant way. Simply closing then reopening Visual Studio results in the same freezing issue for me.